# Возможно ли задать Expandable Listview иерархию вложенности в виде линий?

Tags: java, android, treeview

Как я понял у Android нет элемента `Treeview` с возможностью отображения линий вложенности, для создания вложенности можно использовать `ExpandableListView` и в итоге получим такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

путем кастомизации можно его красиво украсить. 
Но не ясно одно,почему нет возможности отрисовки этой вложенности в виде дерева(линий):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли вообще реализовать отрисовку линиями?

Comment: В сети есть несколько реализаций `TreeView`, но без этих линий "а ля Windows Explorer". Я думаю, что можно написать - может напишем совместно?

Comment: да, я делал такое 1 в 1, только у меня кругляшки были, найду скину сюда

Comment: я невижу проблемы сделать подобное, вижу уже как минимум два варианта. Первый это использовать картинки или xml, а второй это использовать рисовку линий програмно.

Comment: @ Shwarz Andrei 
надеюсь на вас,только не кидайте библиотеку androidtreeview,я ее видел

Comment: @ Максим Кузнецов
на словах и у меня получалось

Comment: ч.т.д)невозможно)

Comment: Ну дык, будем вместе делать или будем дальше болтать?

Comment: @Barmaley
я за,с чего начать7)